# Designing a relay

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to build a relay but I always get an error that doesn't make any sense to me.

The error says that a ground object is missing or a component is not connected,
but I can't find anything missing.

I tried to build the relay in different ways but always the same error...

[image]

My class for testing the relay:

```
model test

Relay relay  annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,4},{0,24}})));
ConstantVoltage constantVoltage annotation (Placement(transformation(
    extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
    rotation=-90,
    origin={-74,10})));
ConstantVoltage constantVoltage1 annotation (Placement(transformation(
    extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
    rotation=-90,
    origin={52,12})));
Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-42,-30},{-22,-10}})));
equation 
connect(relay.n1, constantVoltage.n)  annotation (Line(
  points={{-20,9},{-46,9},{-46,0},{-74,0}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(constantVoltage.p, relay.p1)  annotation (Line(
  points={{-74,20},{-48,20},{-48,19},{-20,19}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(relay.n1, ground.p)  annotation (Line(
  points={{-20,9},{-26,9},{-26,-10},{-32,-10}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(relay.p2, constantVoltage1.p)  annotation (Line(
  points={{0,19},{26,19},{26,22},{52,22}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(constantVoltage1.n, relay.n2)  annotation (Line(
  points={{52,2},{26,2},{26,9},{0,9}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
connect(ground.p, relay.n2)  annotation (Line(
  points={{-32,-10},{-16,-10},{-16,9},{0,9}},
  color={0,0,255},
  smooth=Smooth.None));
annotation (Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false, extent={{-100,
        -100},{100,100}}), graphics));
 end test;
```

relay class:
very simple, I just look at v1, if the voltage is positive, the relay should let the current through.

```
model Relay
extends Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.TwoPort;

Boolean off;

equation 
off = v1 < 0;

v2 = if off then 0 else v2;
i2 = if off then 0 else i2;

annotation (Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false, extent={{-100,
        -100},{100,100}}), graphics));
end Relay;
```

error log:

```
Check of MTS.test:

The model has the same number of unknowns and equations: 27

The problem is structurally singular.
It has 27 scalar unknowns and 27 scalar equations.
The Real part has 26 unknowns and 26 equations.
The Integer part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.
The Boolean part has 1 unknowns and 1 equations.
The String part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.

Attempting to further localize singularity.

Singularity of MTS.test is at the top level.

The model MTS.test is structurally singular.

The problem is structurally singular for the element type Real.
The number of scalar Real unknown elements are 26.
The number of scalar Real equation elements are 26.

The model includes the following hints:
An electrical current cannot be uniquely calculated.
The reason could be that
- a ground object is missing (Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground)
to define the zero potential of the electrical circuit, or
- a connector of an electrical component is not connected.

The problem has no elements of type Integer.

The problem is structurally regular for the element type Boolean.
The number of scalar Boolean elements are 1.

The problem has no elements of type String.

ERROR: 2 errors were found

WARNING: 2 warnings were issued
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach that may be worth investigating:

Using a variable resistor on the switch side, and if the switch is open then set the resistance to very large and if it is closed set the resistance to very small.

There are probably more accurate methods but you could probably implement this in such a way to avoid events.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, the thing that strikes me is that you don't have any load in either circuit.  It says it cannot compute the current but the ground issue is only a hint.  Looking at the circuit, you have to ask yourself, what would these circuits do if there was no ground?  Without a load of some kind in the circuit, I don't see a way to compute the currents in either loop.

So try putting some resistors in each loop and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think i2 and v2 should be simultaneously zero in your relay model.  Try this instead. One side is an ideal voltage sensor.  The other is open below a set voltage and a short above it.  As another response noted, you will need to add a series load to solve for the current.
        model Relay
         extends Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.TwoPort;
         Boolean off;
         parameter Modelica.SIunits.Voltage disconnectVoltage = 0;

```
   equation 
     off = v1 < disconnectVoltage;
     i1=0;
     if off then
       i2 = 0;
     else
       v2 = 0;
     end if;
   end Relay;
```

If you must avoid any loads in your model, you could build something like this using one of the ideal switches from the Modelica Standard Library.  They include small resistances and conductances so it should be possible to solve for current in your example without adding a load.

```
model relay2

  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Ideal.IdealOpeningSwitch idealOpeningSwitch 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
        rotation=-90,
        origin={60,0})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sensors.VoltageSensor voltageSensor annotation (
      Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,10},{10,-10}},
        rotation=-90,
        origin={-60,0})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Logical.GreaterThreshold greaterThreshold(threshold=0) 
    annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{10,-10},{-10,10}},
        rotation=180,
        origin={0,0})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.PositivePin p1
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,50},{-90,70}})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.NegativePin n1
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-70},{-90,-50}})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.PositivePin p2
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,50},{110,70}})));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.NegativePin n2
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-70},{110,-50}})));
  annotation (Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=true,extent={{-100,-100},
            {100,100}}), graphics), uses(Modelica(version="3.2")));
equation 

  connect(greaterThreshold.u, voltageSensor.v) annotation (Line(
      points={{-12,0},{-12,0},{-50,0},{-50,0}},
      color={0,0,127},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(idealOpeningSwitch.control, greaterThreshold.y) annotation (Line(
      points={{50,0},{45,0},{15,0},{15,0},{15,0}},

      color={255,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));

  connect(idealOpeningSwitch.n, n2) annotation (Line(
      points={{60,-10},{60,-60},{100,-60}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(idealOpeningSwitch.p, p2) annotation (Line(
      points={{60,10},{60,60},{100,60}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(voltageSensor.p, p1) annotation (Line(
      points={{-60,10},{-60,60},{-100,60}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
  connect(voltageSensor.n, n1) annotation (Line(
      points={{-60,-10},{-60,-60},{-100,-60}},
      color={0,0,255},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
end relay2
```